# How can non-standard python libraries be imported at execution of a python script that is being executed by SSIS?

Tags: python, sql-server, ssis

We currently use SSIS as a job scheduler and workload manager for our Data Lake and Datawarehouse. We would like to move away from this eventually but for now it is the requirement. There are variables that must be passed between the SSIS execution and the execution of scripts that give the script some context. I have set this up to run C# scripts when we need to access API's and it runs smoothly. The issue is we have hit our first requirement to run a python script as part of our load.

We followed a very helpful guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DE1YeELBw_A

It is very similar in appearance to setting up the C# scripts; however, we quickly ran into a few problems. The first of which is with specific libraries. The Python script we are attempting to execute through SSIS uses some "standard" libraries (pandas, numpy, sys) and by adding some message boxes, we are able to confirm that these are importing without an issue when SSIS kicks off the script. The trouble is when we get to libraries that required a PIP install. The first example of this is SqlAlchemy. As soon as the script get's to the line "import SQLAlchemy" it fails and won't even return a standard error message through a try/except pattern that should print the error message into a message box.

What steps are required in order to run python scripts with more advanced libraries using SSIS? OR, is it better to have SSIS kick off a SQL task and within the SQL task leverage the new "Machine Learning Services" on Sql Server?

We tried adding "pip install sqlalchemy" to the script in question
We tried adding double quotes around the execute process task argument

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change where we ran our pip install. Running pip install inside the jupyter notebook did not make the library available to the SSIS execute process task. Running pip install in the command prompt for the required libraries did make the library available when executing the script through SSIS.

I don't fully understand why, we figured this out through troubleshooting and experimenting. If anyone happens to read this and understands why this would make a difference, it would be great if you could link some documentation or try to explain it.

Comment: Or, to rephrase, use the correct Python environment, with the correct packages. SSIS doesn't have special support for Python. A Process task runs Python scripts the same way you'd run them from a console. If you want to use specific packages, you need to install them. Or create a self-contained package with eg PyInstaller. The resulting package contains all environment packages though and can get very big

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Where I get confused is that including the pip install in the script we are running didn't resolve the problem. I thought having pip install in the script would ensure that the currently used environment would add the required packages if they were missing.

Comment: That's *precisely* because running a script gets no special treatment. It's no different than running the script in a console or as a scheduled job. It runs using the settings and environment of the specific user, which, in this case, it whoever runs the package. It uses the path and environment variables set for that user, or through the `Process` task. If you want controllable execution, put all such scripts in the same file and create a virtual Python environment in that folder. This way, you won't have to wonder how the SQL Server Agent or SSIS execution account is set up

Comment: Again, thank you for the comment. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me understand this problem. If you have a moment and wouldn't mind, can you link any sort of documentation or videos where this can be explained in more detail? It is clearly something I need to better understand. If the script runs using the environment of the specific user, and within the script is "pip install sqlalchemy"; does sqlalchemy get installed for the environment that the script is using?